# Error listening to audio on davinci resolve

Tags: linux, audio, debian, alsa, davinci-resolve

I am getting these errors when trying to listen to audio on davinci resolve 18 on Debian.

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:972:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) 
The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
```

This is the contents of my asoundrc file

```shell
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "mixer"
}

pcm.mixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        rate 44800
        format S32_LE
    }
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

Can anyone assist me editing this asoundrc file so that I can have mic and audio working? My mic audio works.

Here's my aplay -l

```shell
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
lavrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Libav/FFmpeg Library
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
speex
    Plugin using Speex DSP (resample, agc, denoise, echo, dereverb)
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
default
mixer
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=Generic,DEV=0
    HD-Audio Generic, ALC293 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic
    USB Stream Output
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort it out

```shell
pcm.dmixed {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
        rate 48000
        channels 2
        format S16_LE
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
    }
}

pcm.dsnooped {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 2048
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
        rate 48000
        channels 2
        format S16_LE
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
    }
}

pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "dmixed"
    }
    capture.pcm {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "dsnooped"
    }
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

I needed to create a capture device, i used dsnoop to create this device then i was able to get davinci to start playing and recording audio.